# TypeError: axios.request is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

The following statement is giving me a `err: TypeError: axios.request is not a function` when I run the api.

```
const content = await axios.request(getData(id)).then(res => res.data)
```

Where getData returns a configuration object.

I am importing axios like so:
`import * as axios from 'axios'`

Comment: Do `import axios from 'axios'` what you're doing imports the namespace.

Comment: Do `import axios from 'axios';
`

Comment: If I do that I get a `err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined` error

Comment: it should be `axios .get()` I don't think `axios.request` is valid

Comment: My question is with axios.request because I have a configuration obejct that I want to pass to my axios request.

Comment: docs: https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosrequestconfig

Answer (score 2):

When we look at axios [type definition file](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L152), we can see that it uses `default export`. So, instead of using `import * as axios from axios`, the correct way is using import for default.

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.request({ // params });
```

Tested in vscode, it didn't give compile error.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @deerwan, unfortunately that does not fix the issue I posted later when I implement this change:  `err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined`

Comment: @agomez interesting, btw, in your previous code `const content = await axios.request(getData(id)).then(res => res.data)`, when using await, it is not supposed to have `then`. So, it must be `const res = await axios.request(getData(id)); const data = res.data;`

Answer (score 0):

@deerawan's Answer looks correct.

but still you are confused you can refer axios reference page.

https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index